# postgres like - matching any 1 or 0 chars

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm reading the [postgres docs on the like keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html), and I see:

> An underscore (_) in pattern stands for (matches) any single character; a percent sign (%) matches any sequence of zero or more characters.

Is there any way to match any single or no characters?

#### Examples:

For the purpose of the examples, I'm using the `∆` char as the operator I'm looking for:

`like 'a∆b'`:
'ab' - > True
'acb' -> True
'a-b' -> True
'a.b' -> True
'a..b' -> False
'ba' -> False
...

Comment: ... = 'ab' OR LIKE 'a_b' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a regular expression for that:

```
where the_column ~ '^a.{0,1}b$'
```

The regex means:

- starts with `a` (`^` anchors at the start)
- followed by zero or one character (`.` matches any character, `{0,1}` is zero or one repetitions)
- and ends with `b` (`$`anchors at the end)

Comment: I guess `?` also means 0 or 1 in a regular expression